# You Tube videos on Android

Tags: android, youtube

I want to  display a certain YouTube channel's videos and allow the user to select one of their videos to watch on Android. Are there any Json Or Xml data is available for this? Anybody help me where i want to start? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can,
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Username/uploads?&v=2&max-results=30&alt=jsonc
this link give the JSON Data's

Or

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Username/uploads?&v=2&max-results=30
this link give the XML Data's

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can find all the information on getting data from YouTube at the [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) page.

Comment: thanks Kcoppock..can u prefer me any android tutorial for this..?

Comment: For what? There are a LOT of steps for what you're wanting to do. Do you know how to build an Android application? How to parse JSON? How to make the API request? How to display a video in Android?

Comment: I want to get the Json Data...rest of the thing i can figured out

Comment: Here is the reference for the Java library: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java.html